# Show a div only if a particular class has been executed prior to it

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<div class="home_breadCrumbs">
<div class=" home icon" title="Home" ng-click="gotoHome()"  
  draggable="false">home</div>
  <div class="bread-crumbs-arrow-icon"></div></div>
```

I am trying to display the arrow icon only after home like:
home > 
It works smooth in chrome and firefox ;but in IE it's displaying arrow first and then home icon. No clue why;

Is it possible to add some mandatory condition for the arrow icon to be shown only after the home icon has been displayed?

I found out that one of my classes is using "display: inline-flex" as an attribute. I am targetting IE-10. what can i write for the same in IE?

```
home_breadcrumbs{
display: inline-flex;
font-family: arial! important;
font-size: 13px;
height: 20px;}
```

Comment: Try putting the arrow inside the home div? or make it a span inside the home div?

Comment: tried that.. no luck mate!

Comment: Use pseudo selector :after and `position` it `absolute`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `display: inline-block` for both elements.

Comment: didnt work. whats the "inline-flex" equivalent in IE?

Comment: flexbox isn't supported on IE, so you can't use inline-flex. It would be nice if you could post the HTML and CSS so we could see how it's actually being rendered.

Comment: please see my edits;it shows the class which uses inline-flex

Comment: can you try replacing inline-flex with inline-block? it seems a bit overkill to use flexbox just to display 2 divs beside each other.

Comment: i tried with inline-block; but it didnt work; tried -ms-inline-flex; flexbox too